# Why does Hibernate not support nested transactions outside of Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, nested

I am using Hibernate4 but not Spring. In the application I am developing I want to log a record of every Add, Update, Delete to a separate log table. As it stands at the moment my code does two transactions in sequence, and it works, but I really want to wrap them up into one transaction.

I know Hibernate does not support nested transactions, only in conjunction with Spring framework. I´ve read about savepoints, but they´re not quite the same thing.

Comment: What is your definition of "nested transaction", if it doesn't involve savepoint? What makes you thing that Spring is able to use Hibernate transactions in a way that you wouldn't be able to use yourself?

Comment: @JBNizet. From the reading Ive done if one is using Spring transactions then if either operation fails, the other MUST be rolled back

Comment: There is nothing of that sort in Spring (and anywhere else, because that's just not how transactions work). What exists in Spring is simple transaction propagation: if a transactional method is called from another transactional method, then the second method doesn't start a transaction: it executes in the context of the first one. But that's also what Hibernate does: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#beginTransaction--

Comment: How does the second transaction "execute in the context of the first one"? Because if you have started a transaction and have not committed nor rolled back, you most definitely will get an error message from Hiberbate stating "Nested transactions not supported"?

Comment: No, you won't. I don't see why you would get that. Spring won't ever ask to Hibernate to start a nested transaction. It will see that a transactin is already started, and won't try to start another one. Instead of speculating on what will happen, why don't you try it, read the Spring documentation, and ask a concrete question, with code, if you're stuck on a real problem?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the standards regarding JPA and JTA specification has support for nested transactions.

What you most likely mean with support by spring is @Transactional annotations on multiple methods in a call hierarchie. What spring does in that situation is to check is there an ongoing transaction if not start a new one.

You might think that the following situation is a nested transaction.

```
@Transactional
public void method1(){
    method2(); // method in another class
}

@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)
public void method2(){
    // do something
}
```

What happens in realitiy is simplified the following. The type of *transactionManager1* and *transactionManager2* is *javax.transaction.TransactionManager*

```
// call of method1 intercepted by spring
transactionManager1.begin();
// invocation of method1 
// call of method 2 intercepted by spring (requires new detected)
transactionManager1.suspend();
transactionManager2.begin();
// invocation of method2
// method2 finished
transactionManager2.commit();
transactionManager1.resume();
// method1 finished
transactionManager1.commit();
```

In words the one transaction is basically on pause. It is important to understand this. Since the transaction of transactionManager2 might not see changes of transactionManager1 depending on the transaction isolation level.

Maybe a little background why I know this. I've written a prototype of distributed transaction management system, allowing to transparently executed methods in a cloud environment (one method gets executed on instance, the next method might be executed somewhere else).

Comment: Ok, I understand from your code above what Spring does, but that scenario doesnt match what Im trying to achieve, which is have ALL operations that affect the data (add, delete, update) on more than one table either succeed entirely or fail completely. The scenario described by you is of two trx interacting. My case: I do not want some tables to be affected while others are not. Sorry if that wasnt clear from my description of the question/problem.

Comment: @DJoyce remove `propagation=REQUIRES_NEW`, and that's what will happen. The default is `propagation=REQUIRED`. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED

Comment: You should add a test in your algorithm, transactionManager1 will not commit his changes to the databases if transaction Manager2 in failed. But I agree with your preposition